# Synchronizing multiple YouTube video's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

What would be the best way to play multiple YouTube at once? I want them to be synced at the millisecond and therefore not to be affected by buffering issues, or advertisements of different lengths.

**Update 1:**

I think my question would be answered sufficiently if I would get an answer to the following question:

How can you detect using the javascript API of YouTube when the video is able to play (video has buffered sufficiently to be able to play / advertisement is not playing / video is not halted for any other reason)?

**update 2:**

The basic idea of YouTube syncing has been done by [SwigView](http://www.swigview.com/). The only thing missing is is for the video's to be synced more precisely at which SwigView  didn't do a great job implementing.

I am starting to doubt it is even possible with the current API and I am looking at alternative approaches.

Comment: A long shot but did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @BenEverard I never did. I continued by creating my own (html5) video system.

Comment: Got ya, thank you for replying :-)

Comment: @Joren: Hi I'm also looking for a solution to do this. If it's a public project where you solved this, please post a link. All help highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to sync two YouTube iFrame API players within a tolerance of 0.2s or better by measuring and adjusting the time difference between the two players in regular intervals. For example, the adjustment for a time difference of X milliseconds can be done pretty accurately by doubling or halving the playback speed of one player and setting it back to normal speed after X/2 milliseconds. Helpers for user interaction (stop, play, pause) can be added from the regular API repertoire. They also cover advertisements, since they pause the players.

Code to clarify:

## script.js

```
// the players
var player1;
var player2;

// the rules
var syncThreshold=0.2; // seconds, threshold for an acceptable time difference to prevent non-stop syncing
var jumpThreshold=2; // seconds, threshold for a time difference that should be corrected by a rough jump
var jumpDeadTime=500; // milliseconds, a dead time in which we don't sync after a jump

// timeouts and intervals
var timeSyncInterval;
var syncActionTimeout=undefined;

// The YouTube API calls this once it's ready
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player1 = new YT.Player('somediv1', {
    videoId: 'zkv-_LqTeQA',
    events: {
      onReady: syncTime,
      onStateChange: syncStateChange
    }
  });
  player2 = new YT.Player('somediv2', {
    videoId: 'zkv-_LqTeQA'
  });
}

// the syncing magic
function syncTime(){
  // making sure the syncing interval has not been set already for some reason
  clearInterval(timeSyncInterval);
  // setting a 1s interval in which we check it the players are in sync and correct in necessary
  timeSyncInterval = setInterval(function () {
    // if the timeout is already set, we are already trying to sync the players, so we don't have to do it again
    if(syncActionTimeout==undefined){
      // measure the time difference and calculate the duration of the sync-action
      var time1=player1.getCurrentTime();
      var time2=player2.getCurrentTime();
      var timeDifference=time2-time1;
      var timeDifferenceAmount=Math.abs(timeDifference);
      var syncActionDuration=1000*timeDifferenceAmount/2;

      if(timeDifferenceAmount>jumpThreshold){
        // the players are too far apart, we have to jump
        console.log("Players are "+timeDifferenceAmount+" apart, Jumping.");
        player2.seekTo(player1.getCurrentTime());
        // we give the player a short moment to start the playback after the jump
        syncActionTimeout=setTimeout(function () {
          syncActionTimeout=undefined;
        },jumpDeadTime);
      }else if(timeDifference>syncThreshold){
        // player 2 is a bit ahead of player 1, slowing player 2 down
        console.log("Player 2 is "+timeDifference+"s ahead of player 1. Syncing.");
        player2.setPlaybackRate(0.5);
        // setting a timeout that fires precisely when both players are sync
        syncActionTimeout=setTimeout(function () {
          // the players should be sync now, so we can go back to normal speed
          player2.setPlaybackRate(1);
          syncActionTimeout=undefined;
        },syncActionDuration);
      }else if(timeDifference<-syncThreshold){
        console.log("Player 1 is "+(-timeDifference)+"s ahead of player 2. Syncing.");
        // player 1 is bit ahead of player 2, slowing player 2 down
        player2.setPlaybackRate(2);
        // setting a timeout that fires precisely when both players are sync
        syncActionTimeout=setTimeout(function () {
          // the players should be sync now, so we can go back to normal speed
          player2.setPlaybackRate(1);
          // undefining the timeout to indicate that we're done syncing
          syncActionTimeout=undefined;
        },syncActionDuration);
      }
    }
  },1000);
}

// a little helper to deal with the user
function syncStateChange(e){
  if(e.data==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){
    player2.seekTo(player1.getCurrentTime());
    player2.playVideo();
  }else if(e.data==YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){
    player2.seekTo(player1.getCurrentTime());
    player2.pauseVideo();
  }
}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Sync Two Youtube Videos</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- CDN -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad"></script>

    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <!-- HOSTED -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="somediv1"></div>
  <div id="somediv2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari has issues. There's a lag when seeking/changing playback speed in Safari, that puts the videos out of sync pretty much right away and stutters harshly. I know this is super old now, but any idea how that could be fixed?